# Not possible to extract tar.gz archive in Centos

Tags: centos, tar, archive

I have just uploaded tar.gz archive to my Centos server from my home Windows 7 computer. Before that, it was extracted from .zip archive.

When I try to extract it:

```
tar -xvf file.tar.gz
gunzip file.tar.gz
```

It always give me error:
"not in gzip format"

The archive is not corrupted, because it is possible to extract it in Windows with Winrar.

The archive is quite big, more than 100 MB.

I don't know, what's the problem. Could you help me please? Thanks.

Peter

Comment: Have you tried not including the "-" in front of xvf?

Comment: Firstly, can we find out what the file really is; can you do a `file file.tar.gz` and post the results in your question?

Comment: The file command returns "data" as the file type.

Comment: Then you might think it's not corrupt, but CentOS disagrees.  A proper gzipped file should return "gzip compressed data...", an uncompressed tarfile "POSIX tar archive...".  How did you transfer the file from the Win7 box?

Comment: I have uploaded it via ssh tunnel (Tunnelier).

Comment: I don't know that, so can't comment on it.  You might try moving the original zip file across, and try `unzip -t foo.zip` on it, to see if extracting the contained tgz file on linux will work any better.

Comment: try: tar -zxvf file.tar.gz

Comment: You don't need to repackage a .zip file into .tar.gz before uploading it to your server. You can `unzip` the zip file directly.... `yum install unzip`

Comment: I am uploading the whole .zip archive now. I will try to extract it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you transferred the file from Windows to Linux in BINARY mode (if using FTP)?

Otherwise:

If under linux system to extract files from the archive, use this:

```
tar -zxvf archive.tar.gz
```

This will both UNgzip and UNtar the files and directories.

Answer (score 1):

Don't really understand this string: "tar -xvf file.tar.gz gunzip file.tar.gz"

```
tar xvf file.tar.gz
```

is  enought to extract gzipped tar archive. Are you sure it is gzipped? Check with following:

```
file file.tar.gz
```

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# file ./file.tar.gz
./file.tar.gz: data

Comment: So, looks like this file is nor tar archive, nor gzip. Probably it's already extracted.